# Django admin custom AdminURLFieldWidget widget misses the Browse button

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

I'm trying to customize Django admin and I need to create a custom URL displayed for a `FileField` record in the `change_form` template. So, by googling I've found the following recipe adpated from a customization of an image field found [here](http://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/06/20/django-simple-admin-imagefield-thumbnail/). Here is my code:

```
class MyAdminURLFieldWidget(URLInput):
    template_name = 'admin/widgets/url.html'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        final_attrs = {'class': 'vURLField'}
        if attrs is not None:
            final_attrs.update(attrs)
        super(MyAdminURLFieldWidget, self).__init__(attrs=final_attrs)


    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(MyAdminURLFieldWidget, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['current_label'] = _('Currently:')
        context['change_label'] = _('Change:')                  
        context['widget']['href'] = smart_urlquote('/DownloadView/' + str(value.instance.id) + '/attachment/') if value else ''
        return context


class FilesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', '_animalid', '_filename', '_filedesc', '_ispublic', 'extra_info')
    search_fields = ('subjectid__animalid',)
    list_per_page = 50

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):                                
        if db_field.name == 'filename':
            request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
            kwargs['widget'] = MyAdminURLFieldWidget            
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)         
        else:
            return super(FilesAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

However, the form display the field without the `Browse button:

[image]

I would like to have something like the default:

[image]

So, how can I make the `Browse` button to appear in my custom widget?

Answer (score 0):

Hello again to the lost Django community,

Here I go with my own answer again. The problem is that the `final_attrs` must be `final_attrs = {'type': 'file'}`.

You are welcome (again).